# The initlization of ArrayPool<T>.Shared

Tags: c#

I understand that using [ArrayPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-6.0) can minimize memory allocation and improve performance and the common usage is like this:

```
var pool = ArrayPool<int>.Shared;
int[] array = pool.Rent(10000);
pool.Return(array);
```

where `ArrayPool<int>.Shared` returns a shared ArrayPool instance which allows us to `Rent()` an array from it. My question is:

- is the underlying memory blocks returns from `Rent()` initialized when the program starts?
- is there a fixed size of the pool or will the pool adjust its size dynamically in the background so that the program will not `Rent()` more memory from the pool then it has?

(Note: [This post](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/) mentioned that the max array length is equal to 2^20 (1024*1024 = 1 048 576). But what I am asking is the size of the pool)

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.shared), "renting a buffer from a shared class [..] will result [..] in a new buffer being allocated if one is not available." Allocating all memory up-front would be silly and offer no benefit (except in limited circumstances where a machine is dedicated to running a single application).

Comment: @JeroenMostert My understanding is that ArrayPool is faster because it pre-allocates certain amount of memory before I need it.

Comment: No, that is *not* why `ArrayPool` is faster -- it's faster because the arrays remain allocated when returned to the pool, which reduces pressure on the garbage collector, and because it may re-use an array by giving you one that's already allocated but larger than what you strictly need. True, in order to speed up initial allocations the implementation might choose to pre-allocate some arrays of some sizes, but this is is an implementation detail and definitely not a restriction on the total size. Allocation is (fairly) cheap, garbage collection is what's expensive.

Comment: Actually, scratch even the remark about speeding up initial allocations -- pre-allocating things makes some sense to ensure initial memory for pooled arrays is unfragmented (so irregular, unpooled allocations don't mess things up in the beginning). Even then it doesn't make sense to allocate lots of memory for this purpose. The idea behind `ArrayPool` remains sound even if no memory at all is allocated up front and the first memory is allocated only when you `Rent()` for the first time.

Comment: What you said is reasonable. But where do you get this information? From documents or source code.

Comment: The idea behind `ArrayPool` is partially explained in the docs for `ArrayPool` itself, but also in background articles like [this one](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/). Reading source is not required; you can check the source if you're particularly curious about whether (some) memory is allocated up-front, but as I've mentioned this is a detail and could change over releases.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to answer the question if you read the source code:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.13/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool.cs#L80

> is the underlying memory blocks returns from Rent() initialized when the program starts?

No.

> is there a fixed size of the pool or will the pool adjust its size dynamically in the background so that the program will not Rent() more memory from the pool then it has?

No, the method always return an array.

Comment: I am not asking about `Rent()` and I am asking about `ArrayPool<T>.Shared`...

Comment: As you can see the [constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.13/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool.cs#L60) of `ArrayPool<T>.Shared` doesn't allocate any memory, `Rent` does.